# How should i programme this

Tags: matlab

[image]

```
f=1/abs(λ-a-b*exp(-λ))
```

I would like to plot this in the Re-Im axis. 

'a' and 'b' are constants (`a=5`, `b=-5`)

λ is a complex number like  `λ = Re + i*Im`

I have tried this:

```
Re=linspace(-5,5,100);
Im=linspace(-5,5,100);
λ=Re+1*i*Im;
f=1./abs(λ-a-b*exp(-λ));
plot(f)
```

But axis are not Re-Im and it doesn't look like it has to!

Comment: It is not possible to use `λ` as a variable name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To plot complex data you can use:

```
plot(f, '.');
```

However I think there might be something else that is wrong with your logic. Do you want to display the value of `f` for each possible combination of `a` and `b`? Then you have to use `meshgrid`

```
a = 5; b = -5;
Re=linspace(-5,5,100);
Im=linspace(-5,5,100);
[Re,Im] = meshgrid(Re,Im);
l=Re+1i*Im;
f=1./abs(l-a-b*exp(-l));
surf(Re, Im, f)
```

Comment: yes you're right i have to do it for each a and b from -5 to +5

Comment: Wait that is different, the code is now sweeping the complex value `l` and not `a` and `b`! So you want to change `a` and `b`, what do you want `l` do be then?

Comment: l is still complex

Comment: but what is it's value? Or do you want to sweep it as well, then this is no longer a 2D-problem...

Comment: well i think im wrong so i have to seacrh more.
Thanks for help anyway :)